# uninitialized constant Bundler::thor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rbenv

I've just installed rails `6.0.2.2` on `wsl` using `rbenv` and i am getting the below error on my first app bundle.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        7: from /home/bottles/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
        6: from /home/bottles/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        5: from /home/bottles/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:34:in `<top (required)>'
        4: from /home/bottles/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:123:in `with_friendly_errors'
        3: from /home/bottles/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:36:in `block in <top (required)>'
        2: from /home/bottles/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:36:in `require_relative'
        1: from /home/bottles/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/bottles/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:6:in `<module:Bundler>': uninitialized constant Bundler::Thor (NameError)
```

I have no idea on how to fix this. I have tried various numerous ways.

Comment: Did you try `rm -rf .bundle/` and `rm -rf Gemfile.lock` and then `bundle install`?

Comment: its  my first bundle and its unsuccessfully so i got no Gemfile.lock but i have also tried that already though, still same error

Comment: Ok, maybe something wrong in `rails`, try uninstalling rails and bundler, then install bundler, then latest `rails 6.0.3.1`